# PHP keys exist in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have three arrays:

```
$arr_1 = array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);  
$arr_11 = array('a'=>1, 'd'=>4);  
$arr_2 = array('a'=>'aaa','b'=>'bbb', 'c'=>'ccc');
```

I want to check that all keys from $arr_1 exist in $arr_2.

```
someFunction($arr_1,$arr_2); //return true  
someFunction($arr_11,$arr_2); //return false
```

I know how to do it with a "foreach" loop.
Is there a better way?

Comment: http://php.net/array_key_diff - Compares the keys from *array1* against the keys from *array2* and returns the difference. This function is like `array_diff()` except the comparison is done on the keys instead of the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe

```
<?php

array_diff(array_keys($arr_1), array_keys($arr_11));

?>
```

shorter yes, faster dunno :)

Update from @deceze

```
<?php 

array_diff_key($arr_1, $arr_11);

?>
```

Comment: I never used before so i didn't know that func exists. Thx I add it.

Comment: from this I get 'c','d'. I won't know form which array the are from

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this just going to return all of the keys that are unique to one or the other array? If so, how does he know which array had the "extra" key?

Comment: @lvil You want to check whether one array contains keys not in the other. So if the diff operation contains *anything*, it means that one arrays contained more keys. Read the manual for what exactly the return value means.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw `array_key_diff` is not symmetric. It only returns keys from the first argument that aren't present in any of the others, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach to check if all keys in `$arr1` are present in `$arr2`:

```
function check($v){
    return array_key_exists($v,$arr_2);
}
count(array_filter(array_keys($arr_1),"check")) == count($arr_1); // true
```

Note that while you might not have write the loop out yourself, inevitably any sort of search for keys in an array is going to involve one.

Answer (score 0):

Write `someFunction` yourself, and use a loop inside. A loop and `array_key_exists` is the way to do this, but you can save yourself having to do it again in the future if you wrap it in a function.

**UPDATE**

```
function arrayKeyCompare($control, $variable) {
    foreach (array_keys($control) as $key) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $variable)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) or `isset()` in a while loop:

```
$found_missing_key = false
$keys = array_keys($array1);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    if(!isset($array2[$key])) {
        $found_missing_key = true;
        break;
    }
}
```